# Error running gulp sass

Tags: node.js, sass, ionic-framework

I start with ionic. Many people faced the same mistakes but i tried all answers I found, I didn't get a result.

When I ran : ionic setup sass, i got this error at the end

Successful npm install

```
Updated F:\Documents\SED\Appli\Demo\www\index.html <link href> references to sass compiled css

Ionic project ready to use Sass!
 * Customize the app using scss/ionic.app.scss
 * Run ionic serve to start a local dev server and watch/compile Sass to CSS

F:\Documents\SED\Appli\Demo\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:22
    throw new Error('`libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?');
    ^

Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
    at getBinding (F:\Documents\SED\Appli\Demo\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:22:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Documents\SED\Appli\Demo\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:188:23)



at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Documents\SED\Appli\Demo\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:3:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)

Exception with  (CLI v1.6.4)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.8
OS: null
Node Version: v4.0.0
```

I tried to re-install gulp and I got this error :

```
$ npm install gulp-sass
npm WARN package.json demo@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json demo@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json demo@1.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN deprecated pangyp@2.3.2: use node-gyp@3+, it does all the things





> node-sass@2.1.1 install F:\Documents\SED\Appli\Demo\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Can not download file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sass/node-sass-binaries/v2.1.1/win32-x64-node-4.0/binding.node

> node-sass@2.1.1 postinstall F:\Documents\SED\Appli\Demo\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 status code downloading 64-bit node.lib
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (F:\Documents\SED\Appli\Demo\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\pangyp\lib\install.js:403:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onRequestResponse (F:\Documents\SED\Appli\Demo\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\pangyp\node_modules\request\request.js:1255:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:415:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:88:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:305:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "F:\\Documents\\SED\\Appli\\Demo\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\pangyp\\bin\\node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd F:\Documents\SED\Appli\Demo\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
gyp ERR! pangyp -v v2.3.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
gulp-sass@1.3.3 node_modules\gulp-sass
├── clone@0.1.19
├── map-stream@0.1.0
├── vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.1.4 (source-map@0.1.43)
├── gulp-util@3.0.6 (array-differ@1.0.0, array-uniq@1.0.2, beeper@1.1.0, lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0, lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0, lodash._reescape@3.0.0, object-assign@3.0.0, replace-ext@0.0.1, minimist@1.2.0, vinyl@0.5.3, chalk@1.1.1, lodash.template@3.6.2, through2@2.0.0, multipipe@0.1.2, dateformat@1.0.11)
└── node-sass@2.1.1 (get-stdin@4.0.1, object-assign@2.1.1, replace-ext@0.0.1, chalk@0.5.1, cross-spawn@0.2.9, semver@4.3.6, mkdirp@0.5.1, meow@3.3.

enter code here
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: run `sduo npm install node-sass` and then again do sass setup to your project.

Comment: I did it and when I ran ionic setup sass, I got the same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgrade the version of nodeJs and it solved my problem I use the `V0.12.7`

Answer (score 4):

This ([workaround](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-running-gulp-sass/32311/20)) worked form me and fixed all.

Starting with this setup:

Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.5
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.9
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.1 
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v4.1.1
Xcode version: Xcode 6.4 Build version 6E35b

I've found a way to avoid to use 'sudo' command. We need before to fix npm permissions following this: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions and fixing permissions for Node here: http://mawaha.com/permission-fix-node-js/ After this we can check and reinstall software without 'sudo' for npm, n or ionic.

I followed this step:

```
npm install -g n
rm -R node_modules/ 
npm install node-sass@3.3.3 
npm -g install node-gyp@3
npm uninstall gulp-sass
npm install gulp-sass@2 
npm rebuild node-sass 
ionic setup sass
```

Why node-sass@3.3.3? Because it works with latest ionic version: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/pull/4449

Comment: or you can [try this](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-running-gulp-sass/32311/10)

Comment: it's the same link in my post :-) but I suggest to avoid 'sudo' command for npm and ionic

Answer (score 2):

First uninstall `gulp-sass`

```
--> npm uninstall gulp-sass
```

Install new version

```
--> npm install gulp-sass@2
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. The way I got it resolved was to first install gulp-sass as:

```
npm install -g gulp-sass
```

then went to the project directory to install node dependencies as:

```
npm install
```

Then, finally ran:

```
ionic setup sass
```

Success! This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

That URL that's 404'ing:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sass/node-sass-binaries/v2.1.1/win32-x64-node-4.0/binding.node
```

Is being generated from [lib/extensions.js](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/v3.2.0/lib/extensions.js) as such:

```
function getBinaryName() {
  var binaryName;

  if (flags['--sass-binary-name']) {
    binaryName = flags['--sass-binary-name'];
  } else if (process.env.SASS_BINARY_NAME) {
    binaryName = process.env.SASS_BINARY_NAME;
  } else if (pkg.nodeSassConfig && pkg.nodeSassConfig.binaryName) {
    binaryName = pkg.nodeSassConfig.binaryName;
  } else {
    binaryName = [process.platform, '-',
                  process.arch, '-',
                  process.versions.modules].join('');
  }

  return [binaryName, 'binding.node'].join('_');
}
```

Indeed the file does not exist in the repo, so I'm guessing the thing that's gone wrong here is that none of those other `if`s came true, and so it fell down to that URL as a last-resort.

We can probably fix this by ensuring that the `SASS_BINARY_NAME` environment variable is set, or passing in the flag. I don't have time to debug this any further myself today!! Good luck, interwebs.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a **dependency hell** problem with an older NodeJS or NPM version, because older versions of gulp-sass and node-sass do not work with NodeJS version >= 4, see for example https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1166

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @Francesco worked fine with me.

But I just needed one more step: downgrade node.js to the version 0.12.7.

And also to add sudo to the global command lines.

So recapping this is what I had to do:

```
sudo npm install -g n
n 0.12.7
rm -R node_modules/ 
npm install node-sass@3.3.3 
sudo npm -g install node-gyp@3
npm uninstall gulp-sass
npm install gulp-sass@2 
npm rebuild node-sass 
ionic setup sass
ionic serve
```

You can now modify the file scss/ionic.app.scss and check it out.

Comment: Was posting a new answer really necessary?  The OP already posted an answer stating that they needed to downgrade specifically to 0.12.7.

Comment: I felt necessary to take the time to write because the accepted answer was not enough for me. The @francesco solution was good. But it didn't include the downgrade step. So i thought it may be useful for others.

Comment: It's not necessary to summarize the other answers.  All of the information is already here, this answer is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following step

Edit your package.json. Change:

```
"gulp-sass": "^2.?.?"
```

to

```
"gulp-sass": "3.0.0"
```

remoce the node_modules folder and run npm install again.